# How do I link javascript to an express application? On my node server, I receive "GET /json 404" when I start it using npm start. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I am making a basic express/mongodb app by following this article: 
https://zellwk.com/blog/crud-express-and-mongodb-2/

Adding items to the database has worked so far using post requests on a form element. But now I am trying to use update and delete requests through the javascript file main.js (not through the html form like the post request). However, now that I am doing that, the requests are not working. The page still renders, but when I click on the buttons, they don't perform any javascript. Here is my file structure:

```
bin
node_modules
public
    images
    javascripts
    stylesheets
    main.js
routes
    index.js
    quotes.js
    users.js
views
    error.ejs
    index.ejs
app.js
package.json
```

I suspect I am doing something wrong with linking the javascript to the index.ejs file, but I have tried every possible way of linking it in the script tag. I have done:

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="public/main.js"></script>
<script src="../public/main.js"></script>
```

And also did each version of those with the js file in the "javascripts" folder. I think it is a linking issue, but I really don't know what the problem is.

Here is the code for my app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/quotes', (err, database) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    db = database;
});

var index = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.post('/quotes', (req, res) => {
    db.collection('quotes').save(req.body, (err, result) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err);

        console.log('saved to database');
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  var cursor = db.collection('quotes').find().toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    res.render('index.ejs', {quotes: result});
  });
});

app.put('/quotes', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('quotes').findOneAndUpdate({name: 'Yoda'}, {
    $set: {
      name: req.body.name,
      quote: req.body.quote
    }
  }, {
    sort: {_id: -1},
    upsert: true
  }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return res.send(err);
    res.send(result);
  });
});

app.delete('/quotes', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('quotes').findOneAndDelete({name:
    req.body.name},
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) return res.send(500, err);
        res.send({message: 'A darth vadar quote got deleted'});
    });
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  console.log("The problem is: " + err);
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Here is the index.ejs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>quotes</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        May Node and Express be with you.

        <ul class="quotes">
            <% for(var i=0; i<quotes.length; i++) {%>
                <li class="quote">
                    <span><%= quotes[i].name %> once said: "</span><span><%= quotes[i].quote %>."</span>
                </li>
            <% } %>
        </ul>

        <form action="/quotes" method="POST">
            <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name"><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="quote" name="quote"><br>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

        <div>
            <h2>Replace last quote written by Master Yoda with a quote written by Darth Vadar.</h2>
            <button id="update"> Darth Vadar invades! </button>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h2>Delete Darth Vadar's first quote</h2>
            <button id="delete"> Delete first Darth Vadar quote
            </button>
        </div>

        <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the main.js file:

```
var update = document.getElementById('update');

update.addEventListener('click', function() {
    fetch('quotes', {
        method: 'put',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'name': 'Darth Vader',
            'quote': 'I find your lack of faith disturbing'
        })
    }).then(res => {
    if (res.ok) return res.json();
  }).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    window.location.reload(true);
  });
});


var del = document.getElementById('delete');

del.addEventListener('click', function() {
    fectch('quotes', {
        method: 'delete',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'name': 'Yoda'
        })
    })
    .then(res => {
        if (res.ok) return res.json();
    }).then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        window.location.reload(true);
    });
});
```

Comment: I used fetch in the main.js file. In the console, all I get is the GET /json 404 Error: Not Found message repeatedly as requests are continuously made to the server.

Comment: Are you getting this message when loading the page or when clicking the buttons?

Comment: Immediately when I start up the server, before I even load up the page, although the page does load.